# How i use a NSMutableArray in two methods of my .m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, global-variables

I have in my .h file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "SQLClient.h"
 @interface mgrViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
 SQLClientDelegate>{ 
     NSMutableArray *pajaros;
 }
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *miTabla;
 @property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *pajaros;
 @end
```

And in my .m file:

```
#import "mgrViewController.h"
#import "Vista2.h"
#import "SQLClient.h"
@interface mgrViewController ()
@end

@implementation mgrViewController
@synthesize miTabla;
@synthesize pajaros;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
client.delegate = self;
[client connect:@"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx" username:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" password:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx" database:@"xxxxxxxxxxx" completion:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success)
    {    
       pajaros =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [client execute:@"SELECT field FROM table WHERE field='xxxxxxxxx'" completion:^(NSArray* results) {          
               NSMutableString* resulta = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                for (NSArray* table in results)
                    for (NSDictionary* row in table)
                        for (NSString* column in row){
                            //[results appendFormat:@"\n%@ = %@", column, row[column]];
                            [resulta appendFormat:@"\n%@", row[column]];
                            [pajaros addObject:resulta];
                        }
            [client disconnect];
        }];
    }
}];
self.miTabla.delegate = self;
self.miTabla.dataSource = self;
}

 #pragma mark - SQLClientDelegate

- (void)error:(NSString*)error code:(int)code severity:(int)severity
{
    NSLog(@"Error #%d: %@ (Severity %d)", code, error, severity);
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}

- (void)message:(NSString*)message
{
    NSLog(@"Message: %@", message);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return pajaros.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celdaPajaros";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // elementos que contienen cada celda con sus tags
    UILabel *labelTitulo = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:10];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    labelTitulo.text = [pajaros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 70.f;
}
@end
```

I added elements to `NSMutableArray pajaros` in `-(void)viewDidLoad{}`, and my question is, how I can use my `NSMutableArray pajaros` in `-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?.

Thanks :)

If I use count on my NSMutable Array and print that number, the result is 1 (because I selected only A data), but only if I use:

```
...        
[pajaros addObject:resulta];
    }
     NSInteger num = pajaros.count;
     NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)num];
     self.textView.text = inStr;
     [client disconnect];
}];
...
```

But if I perform that count in another part of my .m file show me 0, my next questions becomes why my `NSMutableArray` contains only the data in:

```
 ...        
    [pajaros addObject:resulta];
        }
         [client disconnect];
    }];
    ...
```

?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are already using the array properly. What's the problem? Keep in mind that you load the array asynchronously. You should reload the table view (on the main thread) after loading the array.

Comment: Ok thanks, so i guess i will use [self.miTabla reloadData];, but i don´t know in what fragment of code i will use.

Comment: @rmaddy how i reload the table? Sorry I'm new in Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy I use [self.miTabla reloadData]; and show me only other data because I added others arrays for other labels (this new arrays not contain data from sql query, are fill static form), but the label containing NSMutableArray pajaro show me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

//code here to dequecell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
cell.textLabel.text = [pajaraos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: This code show me nothing, but the NSMutableArray pajaros contain an unique data, I use a textView with the next code for see the unique data after the " [pajaros addObject:resulta];}" code:
  self.textView.text = [pajaros objectAtIndex:0];